# bash paste does not retain line breaks

Tags: linux, bash, paste

My bash script is pasting from file1.txt which has line by line entries into a CSVformat. For example:

File1.txt contains text:

```
John
21-2-2015
some city
"108 Brent Street
Ridgewoods
sometown
somecountry"
```

The converted output for a CSV upload should look like:

```
John,21-2-2015,some city,"108 Brent Street
Ridgewoods
sometown
somecountry"
```

However my code converts it to:

```
John,21-2-2015,some city,"108 Brent Street Ridgewoods sometown somecountry"
```

I would like to retain the line breaks.

My code:

```
paste -sd, file1.txt > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below Perl command.

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/(?s)"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\n(?!$)/,/g' file
John,21-2-2015,some city,"108 Brent Street
Ridgewoods
sometown
somecountry"
```

Add `-i` parameter to save the changes made to that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FPAT` feature of GNU `awk`

```
cat main.awk
BEGIN { 
   FPAT = "([^\n]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
   OFS=","
   RS=""
   ORS="\n"
}
{ $1=$1; print
}
awk -f main.awk <datafile
John,21-2-2015,some city,"108 Brent Street
Ridgewood
sometown
somecountry"
```